# How to input .cls file in rmarkdown?

Tags: class, latex, r-markdown

I would like to use a .cls file when producing pdf file using rmarkdown, how to include this file, where to include it?

```
---
title: "Proposal"
author: "Name Surname"
date: "01/30/2015"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
classoption: a4paper
---
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the `documentclass` and `classoption` in the yaml header (see http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html#latex_options).

*e.g.*, to use Elsevier's `elsarticle.cls` you can change the documentclass from `article` to `elsarticle`

```
---
documentclass: elsarticle
classoption: preprint
---
```

put the file in the same directory as .Rmd file.

Comment: can the .cls file be in a subfolder?

Answer (score -1):

You could use **csl:** command.

```
---
title: "Sample Document"
output: html_document
bibliography: bibliography.bib
csl: biomed-central.csl
---
```

Above, you have an example from http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html

Comment: using a `.csl` for bibliography/reference formatting is NOT the same as using a LaTeX class file (`.cls`), *e.g.*, Elsevier's elserticle.cls (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle)